# Baseball players salary & league

Tags: r, statistics

I'm learning R, and I'm using the Lahman dataset to determine if player's salary influences anything about how they or their team play.  As I'm digging into the data, I am curious to know if a players salary is different depending on what league he plays in (AL or NL).  I wrote this program up to see if they are dependent...and I am surprised to find they are.  Is this how I would go about answering this question?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(Lahman)

#Brings salary information together with batting
bat_salaries <- left_join(Batting,Salaries, suffix = c(".x", ".y"))
bat_salaries <- left_join(bat_salaries, Teams, by = c("yearID", "teamID", "lgID"), suffix = c("_individual", "_team"))

#I noticed the tail of bat_salaries$salary is very heavy after the 3rd IQR - I cut it off to only look at
#data before the 3rd IQR

bat_salaries_iqr3 <- bat_salaries %>%
  filter(salary < 2350000 & salary > 0)

bat_salaries_chi <- bat_salaries_iqr3 %>%
  select(salary) %>%
  mutate(leagID = ifelse(bat_salaries_iqr3$lgID == "NL", 1, 0))

chisq.test(table(bat_salaries_chi), correct = FALSE)


Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  table(bat_salaries_chi)
X-squared = 2462.6, df = 2139, p-value = 1.13e-06
```

Comment: Thanks for posting @Nick. Just a heads up: we can only help you with programming questions here. If you're interested in whether cutting off the 3rd IQR or your choice of statistical test is correct, you might also want to post on Cross Validated: https://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: @divibisan Thank you.  I'll post the question there, as I'm more interested in whether or not the stat test is the correct one.